# Bulk Emailing Domain Usage

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc, bulk-email

i am planning strategy for our bulk **marketing** emails and bulk **recruitment** emails. Shall we use seperate domains for marketing and recruitment bulk emails even if we are using SMTP Relay service of providers like **Critsend** and **Sendgrid**. Reason i am asking as i have read somewhere Domain Reputation is also very important in the long run  and should use main domain : abc.com for normal transactional emails and every day communication with our clients and vendors and use seperate domains for Bulk Emailing.

We do have all these 3 domains (main abc.com, others abc.net and abc.org) for several years with us so we can setup quickly and start using though other 2 new domains have never been used for sending emails till date and we have used our main abc.com for sending transactional emails till date for all these years except once a few years ago for bulk emailing but that few 100 emails only.

Or if we are using your SMTP relay of these providers then the domain reputation of providers is required hence it will not matter whether we use other domains or just use our primary domain for everything?

Please help and advise.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part the from address domain is what your sending reputation is associated with, so yes, I would recommend that you separate by domain.

The sending IP also has some effect, so if you have an especially bad reputation on one domain, it may cause deliverability issues for other domains with otherwise good sending reputation that use the same IPs, so it’s a good idea to split that too.

Comment: thanks @synchro for the answer. So whether you use third party SMTP relay , still your from part plays a vital role. Because in gmail, it shows mailed by : critsend-delivery.com whereas from address is email id of our primary domain. I think for safe side purposes , i will use different domain and different ip addresses.

Comment: Will wait to see if i get some detailed answer on pros and cons of this so that all users gets benefited from the question.